# TensorFlow: different results on different GPUs

Tags: gpgpu, object-detection, tensorflow

#### System information

- **What is the top-level directory of the model you are using**:
  Using unmodified pretrained coco models: faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_11_06_2017, faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017, rfcn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017
- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**:
  No
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**:
  UPDATE: tested on two machines now, both reproduce it:
  Machine 1: Linux Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
  Machine 2: Linux Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**:
  official docker container, with last commit 58fb6d7e257f28cd7934316d6ae7a81ec42a533a
  docker version from 2017-08-24T02:37:57.51182742Z
  [cuda_memtest.log.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/files/1313567/cuda_memtest.log.txt)
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**:
  ('v1.2.0-5-g435cdfc', '1.2.1')
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**:
  N/A
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**:
  From official docker: CUDA 8., cuDNN 5.1.10
- **GPU model and memory**:
  Machine 1: Three nVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080, 12 GB
  Machine 2: Two nVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080, 12 GB
- **Exact command to reproduce**:
  Running object_detection_tutorial.ipynb with different GPUs, either with export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=, or by setting it in the session config.  Version that runs through 3 GPUs several times and compares output is included.

#### Describe the problem

Running on different GPUs yields different results, and GPUs 1 and 2 are not deterministic.  This is using frozen pretrained networks from this repository's linked [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) and the supplied object_detection_tutorial.ipynb with no modifications other than setting the cuda visible_device_list.  The SSD frozen models, however, give identical outputs on the 3 GPUs from what I have seen.

I have also run [cuda_memtest](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cudagpumemtest/) on all 3 GPUs, logs attached

UPDATE: I just tested on a second machine with 2 GPUs, and reproduced the issue.  GPU 0 is deterministic, GPU 1 is not (and often produces bad results).

#### Source code / logs

I've attached the diff of the modified object_detection_tutorial.ipynb which loops over 3 GPUs 3 times and prints out the top box scores, which change depending on the run.  Also attached is a PDF of that ipynb with detections drawn on it.  Text output:

```
> Evaluating image 0
> 
>   Running on GPU 0
>       Top 4 box scores: 
>       Iter 1: [ 0.99978215  0.99857557  0.95300484  0.91580492]
>       Iter 2: [ 0.99978215  0.99857557  0.95300484  0.91580492]
>       Iter 3: [ 0.99978215  0.99857557  0.95300484  0.91580492]
> 
>   Running on GPU 1
>       Top 4 box scores: 
>       Iter 1: [ 0.68702352  0.16781448  0.13143283  0.12993629]
>       Iter 2: [ 0.18502565  0.16854601  0.08074528  0.07859289]
>       Iter 3: [ 0.18502565  0.16854601  0.05546702  0.05111229]
> 
>   Running on GPU 2
>       Top 4 box scores: 
>       Iter 1: [ 0.68702352  0.16781448  0.13143283  0.12993629]
>       Iter 2: [ 0.18941374  0.18502565  0.16854601  0.16230994]
>       Iter 3: [ 0.18502565  0.16854601  0.05546702  0.05482833]
> 
> 
> Evaluating image 1
> 
>   Running on GPU 0
>       Top 4 box scores: 
>       Iter 1: [ 0.99755412  0.99750346  0.99380219  0.99067008]
>       Iter 2: [ 0.99755412  0.99750346  0.99380219  0.99067008]
>       Iter 3: [ 0.99755412  0.99750346  0.99380219  0.99067008]
> 
>   Running on GPU 1
>       Top 4 box scores: 
>       Iter 1: [ 0.96881998  0.96441168  0.96164131  0.96006596]
>       Iter 2: [ 0.9377929   0.91686022  0.80374646  0.79758978]
>       Iter 3: [ 0.90396696  0.89217037  0.85456908  0.85334581]
> 
>   Running on GPU 2
>       Top 4 box scores: 
>       Iter 1: [ 0.9377929   0.91686022  0.80374646  0.79758978]
>       Iter 2: [ 0.9377929   0.91686022  0.80374646  0.79758978]
>       Iter 3: [ 0.9377929   0.91686022  0.80374646  0.79758978]
```

[object_detection_tutorial.diff.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/files/1313430/object_detection_tutorial.diff.txt)

[gpu_output_differences.pdf](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/files/1313428/gpu_output_differences.pdf)

Updated with longer run:
[cuda_memtest.log.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/files/1315285/cuda_memtest.log.txt)

Comment: To clarify, what's the behavior with CUDA_VISIBILE_DEVICES? Is the issue that whichever physical device is "GPU:0" gives deterministic results and the others don't, or is it that different physical devices give different results whatever their device number?

Comment: @AllenLavoie The former, GPU:0 is always the same device and is always deterministic and performing better than the others.  This is true across both machines.  Side note that GPU:0 refers to GPU 2 in nvidia-smi for the 3 GPU machine

Comment: I mean, what happens if you use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to hide all but one of the GPUs (making it GPU:0 in TensorFlow whatever its system designation); does that give consistent results across physical devices?

Comment: @AllenLavoie That is precisely what this test is.  Hiding all but one GPU.  So "Running on GPU 0" means hiding 1 and 2, showing only 0.  It is only consistent on GPU 0.  Running on GPU 1, hiding 0+1, is not consistent, and so forth.